# How to add an extra feature to a maven dependency plugin

Tags: java, maven

I use maven-dependency-plugin to copy jar files of artifactItem, instead of giving artifactItem details at pom.xml as shown below

```
<artifactItem>
                                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                                <version>3.8.2</version>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                                <destFileName>junit.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
```

i am trying to extend the pluging to give artifactItems detail progamatically,by using below class

```
                package com.nuwaza.aqua.sample.dependencymanager;

            import java.io.File;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;

            import org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.ArtifactFactory;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.DefaultArtifactRepository;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.ArtifactRepositoryLayout;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.DefaultRepositoryLayout;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.InvalidVersionSpecificationException;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.VersionRange;
            import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
            import org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo;
            import org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.ArtifactItem;
            import org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.CopyMojo;
            import org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log;
            import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component;
            import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
            import org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.VersionRange;

            /**
             * 
             * @id copy
             * @goal copy
             * @phase package
             * @author anoopab
             */
            public class BundleDataMojo extends CopyMojo {

                @Parameter(required = true)
                private List<ArtifactItem> artifactItems;

                @Component
                protected static ArtifactFactory factory;

                public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
                    super.setArtifactItems(setArtifactDetail());

                    super.execute();
                }

                private List<ArtifactItem> setArtifactDetail() {

                    artifactItems = new ArrayList<ArtifactItem>();
                    ArtifactItem bundle = new ArtifactItem();
                    bundle.setGroupId("junit");
                    bundle.setArtifactId("junit");
                    bundle.setVersion("3.8.2");
                    bundle.setDestFileName("samplejunit.jar");
                    bundle.setType("jar");
                    bundle.setOverWrite("true");

                    artifactItems.add(bundle);
                    return artifactItems;
                }
            }
```

but i getting the following erorr

```
[info] Configured Artifact: junit:junit:3.8.2:jar
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getArtifact(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:166)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.CopyMojo.execute(CopyMojo.java:67)
    at com.nuwaza.aqua.sample.dependencymanager.BundleDataMojo.execute(BundleDataMojo.java:52)
    at com.nuwaza.aqua.sample.dependencymanager.BundleDataMojo.main(BundleDataMojo.java:118)

that is

```
/**
 * Used to look up Artifacts in the remote repository.
 */
@Component
protected ArtifactFactory factory;
```

this factory getting null value..... 
ArtifactFactory  interface at  org.apache.maven.artifact.factory

I'm really confused by these. Could anyone give any help? Thanks a lot!